# Showing Normal Equations as Linear System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

[This is a practice problem]

I watched tutorials on least square method and normal equations and understood them too. However, i am confused with this question:

> Measurement vals $p_0 = 0, p_1 = 2$, and $p_2 = 1$ were obtained at nodes
>   $u_0 = 0, u_1 = 1$, and $u_2 = 2$. Function $p(u) = au + b$ 
>   approximates these values according to the least squares
>   method.Formulate the normal equations as linear system.

Now I have a sample solution where to start, 2 equations are derived as followed:

$\sum p = a\sum u + 3b$ (1)

$\sum up = a\sum u^2 + b\sum u$ (2)

How are these equations derived? I couldn't find any relevant examples online. For the first one I can assume that it's 3b since there are 3 values but I don't understand the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the linear function $p\left(u\right)=au+b$ by $u$ as shown below.
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    u_1p_1 & = & au_1^2 & + & bu_1 \\
    u_2p_2 & = & au_2^2 & + & bu_2  \\
    u_3p_3& = & au_3^2 & + & bu_3  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Now, add them together using the notation of summation.
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 u_ip_i=a\sum_{i=1}^3 u_i^2+b\sum_{i=1}^3 u_i $$

So, you see that there is no 3.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you minimize the squared difference between the observed values $p_i$ and the  fitted value $f(u_i)$.

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^n(p_i-f(u_i))^2,$$

where $f(u_i)=a\cdot u_i+b$ and $n=3$.

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^3(p_i-a\cdot u_i-b)^2,$$

Differentiating $S$ w.r.t $a$ and $b$ and setting these partial derivatives equal to $0$.

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}=\sum_{i=1}^3 2\cdot (p_i-a\cdot u_i-b)\cdot (-u_i)=0$$

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}=\sum_{i=1}^3 2\cdot (p_i-a\cdot u_i-b)\cdot (-1)=0$$

Can you proceed to get the 2 equations in the form you´ve mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & 1 \\
u_2 & 1 \\
u_3 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} ,  \quad
x=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
p =\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\
p_2  \\
p_3 
\end{bmatrix} $$
Then the least-squares solution is the vector of parameters $x$ for which $||Ax - p||_2$ is as small as possible. This solution is also the solution of the normal equations, which are given by
$$ A^TA x = A^Tp.$$